# Entity Framework Code First customize CRUD Operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am working on EF Code First Approach with the existing database. The scenario is as follows:

1. Whenever i insert data, it should generate a customized primary key to be inserted into the DB table.
2. Similarly in case of Delete, it should not perform the delete operation. It should not only modify Deleted field to 1, but also insert data in some other fields like ModificationDate, Time etc.
3. Also let me know if i need to use Stored Procedures in that.

Note: The Primary Key column is a non seed varchar column.

```
public class Child {
    [Key]
    public string ChildCounter { get; set; }
    public string CouncilCode { get; set; }
    public string CentreCode { get; set; }
    public string DateBirth { get; set; }
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string FatherCounter { get; set; }

    public virtual Father Father { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to EF, so any code example should be highly appreciated.

```
  public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Child/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(tblChild tblchild) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.tblChilds.Add(tblchild);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tblchild);
    }


    public ActionResult Delete(string id = null) {
        tblChild tblchild = db.tblChilds.Find(id);
        if (tblchild == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View(tblchild);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Child/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id) {
        tblChild tblchild = db.tblChilds.Find(id);
        db.tblChilds.Remove(tblchild);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**

To set the primary key yourself, add the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None attribute:

```
public class Child
{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]  //<<<<---
   public string ChildCounter { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

This will allow you to set the ChildCounter property to whatever you require.

**2**

To logically delete, you'll need to add a Deleted boolean property or similar to the model and then update rather than delete the object:

```
public class Child
{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public string ChildCounter { get; set; }
   ...
   public bool Deleted {get; set;}  //<<<<---
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    var tblchild = db.tblChilds.Find(id);
    tblchild.Deleted = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You will need to remember to ensure you only pull back non-'deleted' items from the database when you wish to display a list of Child items though:

```
var childItems = db.tblChilds.Where(c => !c.Deleted).ToList();
```

**3**

No need to use Stored Procedures at all for this really.